# А как мне проверить точно ли запустится exe файл от Qt на другой машине

Tags: qt, qt5

Ситуация такая я собрал пакет с Qt програмкой у меня на системе все запускалось. По инструкции по которой я собирал вроде должно бы и на другой машине запуститься. Но когда я пришел к знакомому и кликнул на файл он не запустился. Как мне точно проверить запуститься или нет. Есть мысль запустить виртуалку и там проверять.

Comment: Я использую виртуалку с чистой системой

Comment: Непонятно по какой инструкции вы собирали. Есть ли нужные dll, добавлены ли папки плагинов. А так заведите чистую виртуалку и в ней запускайте программки, тогда уж точно будете уверены, что программы запустятся у других. ЗЫ. у вас запускалось потому что в переменных путях в PATH указаны папки с либами Qt, который конечно же не было у знакомого

Answer (score 0):

Я переименовываю каталог с Qt и, таким образом, обхожусь без виртуалки

Comment: По-моему, проще убрать каталоги Qt из PATH. А переименовывать каталог - плохая идея, их могут использовать какие-либо программы.

Comment: согласен, что так делать не совсем правильно. Но если нужно только проверить готовый пакет на запускаемость, то переименовать каталог будет быстрее, чем править PATH. (ИМХО). И уж точно проще, чем заводить для этих целей виртуалку, если только не нужно проверять для отличной от хостовой системы. Главное не забыть переименовать обратно!

Answer (score 0):

https://evileg.com/ru/post/163/ - необходимо собрать все зависимости с windeployqt. Вообще хорошей практикой будет уметь делать установочники через InnoSetup, например. Тогда вы еще сможете в автоматическом режиме установить другие зависимости типа MS VisualC++ Runtime.